# In codeigniter, better to use models or database views and stored procs?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I want to push the database logic as far down as possible. I am using codeigniter.

Is it better to to push anything having to do with the DB as far down toward the database so that the model makes a simple call OR put it ALL in Models and the DB ONLY contains tables?

For example, should I build stored procs and views to make it easier for the Model to handle complicated queries and joins or have a model handle all joins and DB functions and have no views?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, no, you shouldn't use stored procedure when you can use a `model`. It's better to use models than stored procedures because it'll make your app tightly coupled/depended on the database and it would be hard to test without a database and won't be reusable and would be hard to maintain. Don't use stored procedures unless you have to for very specific reason. Not only in `CodeIgniter` but overall.

**Update :** [A better and detailed answer is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516088/when-to-use-a-stored-procedure-mysql)

Comment: Thanks. Long time developer but new to OOP, trying to understand where the things I have worked with for years, go.

Comment: You are welcome my friend, we all need to continue learning everyday,as i do :-)